# UIFileSharingEnabled has no effect in my cordova app for ios

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, itunes

I've added UIFileSharingEnabled to the .plist. Per suggestions, I have:

1. removed the app and redeployed it several times
2. attempted to disconnect after redeploying
   I have not been able to get the app visible in the File Sharing section in iTunes.
   I have added the plugin [cordova-plugin-itunesfilesharing](https://github.com/christianjunk/cordova-plugin-itunesfilesharing)

Which added UIFileSharingEnabled to the .plist But it has no effect to application .

**Edit:**

I am trying to use `cordova-plugin-itunesfilesharing` I added these `<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key> <true/>` in my .plist file. **I need to turn on itunes file sharing in my ios application.**

Comment: You have done great but would you please write a line to tell us, what you want to do? Means, What you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: cordova-plugin-itunesfilesharing by using that plugin it added these <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>lines in my .plist file. Further it didn't involve any code in it . I just have to add these lines into .plist file after that it will have to turn on itunes file sharing in application.Hope you got my point

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `cordova-plugin-itunesfilesharing`, you also need to put your files in the app's Documents directory to make them visible via iTunes. I'm assuming you're using `cordova-plugin-file` for the actual file writing. In this case, `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` will point to the Documents folder on iOS.

Example:

```
var isAppend = true;
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.documentsDirectory, function (dir) {
  dir.getFile("my_file_name.txt", {create: true}, function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

            fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                console.log("Failed writing to file: " + e.message);
            };

            // If we are appending data to file, go to the end of the file.
            if (isAppend) {
                try {
                    console.log("isAppend = TRUE, seeking log file end");
                    fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log("Failed seeking end of file: " + e.message);
                }
            }
            fileWriter.write(contentToBeWritten);
        }
    );
  });
});
```